# SSIS Excel Source OpenRowset From Variable Error - 0x80040E37

Tags: excel, ssis, bids

When configuring an Excel Data Flow Component (Source) using the `AccessMode` of `OpenRowset from Variable` and setting the correct variable, I get the following error when trying to configure the shape/preview the data:

> TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Exception from HRESULT: 0xC02020E8
>   Error at Merge Files [Excel Source [2]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.
>   Error at Merge Files [Excel Source [2]]: Opening a rowset for "[WORKSHEET]" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.

I have checked that variable name is correctly set to the name of a valid worksheet.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append a dollar sign on the end of the worksheet variable, e.g. WORKSHEET$